# Unable to restore Toad Object Explorer

Tags: toad

I'm using Toad for SQL Server 6.1 and accidently closed the object explorer and connection manager and can't seem to get them back.

If I use View > Object Explorer or Connection Manager nothing at all happens. I can open other options on that menu, eg Output, Toad views, SQL Recalls.

Has anyone come accross this before?

Cheers, Clinton

After back and forward with Dell, they cannot solve the issue either, so a reinstall seems the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to DBrett at Toadworld

I was having a similar issue with Toad Data Point 3.7.0.973. Object Explorer, Navigation Explorer, etc. would not display. Followed Henrik Johnson post to remove the file in the Analyst directory did the trick!

1. Help>About>Application Data Directory>Sessions Folder>
2. Close Toad Data Point
3. Rename Analyst.tss to Analyst_DOT_tss.old
4. Launch TDP
5. Test

http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-sql-server/f/14/p/23057/54306#54306